# Star Rating in Django

Tags: python, django, rating

I've seen other posts about this but still, I'm too dumb :/
So I have this site with products, each product has its unique page-detail where you can leave comments. And now I want to add the possibility to 'star-rate' the product when you write a comment, like in the picture.
Im guessing the first step is to add an Integer field on the "comments model" . But what are the steps from now on ? Im guessing a little JS is needed but i don't rlly know js :/

models.py

```
class CommentsModel(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
component = models.ForeignKey(ProductsModel,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
text = models.TextField(null=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
rating = models.IntegerField(default=0,
    validators = [
        MaxValueValidator(5),
        MinValueValidator(0),
    ]
)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.component.name, self.user.username)
```

views.py

```
def comments_view(request, id):
component = get_object_or_404(ProductsModel, id = id)
comments = CommentsModel.objects.filter(component = component).order_by('-id')

if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentsForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        comment_form = CommentsModel.objects.create(component=component, user=request.user, text=text)
        comment_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(component.get_absolute_url())
else:
    comment_form = CommentsForm()
    
context = {'object':component, 'object2':comments, 'comment_form':comment_form}
return render(request, 'templates/comments/comments.html', context)
```

[this is my site with some stars in the template referring how I d like to look and work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkYkX.png)

forms.py

```
class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CommentsModel
    fields = [
        'text',
    ]
```

template(just the part with the comments) :

```
<div class="container">
    <form  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-2x my-btn" id="first"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-2x my-btn" id="second"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-2x my-btn" id="third"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-2x my-btn" id="fourth"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-2x my-btn" id="fifth"></button>
        <div>
            {{ comment_form.text|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Posteaza" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: white; color: black; border-color: white;">
        {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-succes" style="margin-top: 20px; background-color: white; color: black; border-color: white;" disabled>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    

    <div class="main-comment-section" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        {{ object2.count }} Comentarii
        {% for index in object2 %}
            <figure style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                    <p style="font-weight: 15px;">{{ index.text }}</p>
                </blockquote>
                <figcaption class="blockquote-footer">
                    postat de catre <cite title="Source Title">{{ index.user|capfirst}}</cite>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: So there is two parts you need to solve, first get a rating and second to display the current rating. Your views and the form look like you have the "get a rating" part already now when you show a comment you need to display the amount of start the individual user gave and maybe a average rating per product?

Comment: So the stars u see in the photo are not working, I just put them in the HTML page to see how I want to be.  Basically, I want the user to select  how many stars he want from 1 to 5, write the comment and then  click POST.  And then his comment will appear down along with his star rate.                    The one thing I did so far is adding the field "rating" in the "comments model" and that's it.  I don't know what to to from now on. Put it in form? And then?      PS: yes I would like to be able  to show average rating per product, but that's the last thing. For now, I just want this to work.